# exe file not running (cx_Freeze + PySide)

Tags: pyside, cx-freeze

After freezing my Python programs using cx_freeze, I tried to run exe file created but its not running.

PhoneBook.py

```
import  sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtUiTools import *

class PhoneBook:
  i=0;
  def __init__(self):
        loader = QUiLoader();       
        file = QFile("PhoneBook.ui");   
        file.open(QFile.ReadOnly);  
        self.ui = loader.load(file);    
        file.close();
        self.ui.setWindowIcon(QIcon('web.png'));
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add);
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.load);

  def __del__ ( self ):
        self.ui = None;

  def add(self):
        loader1 = QUiLoader();      
        file1 = QFile("Add.ui");    
        file1.open(QFile.ReadOnly); 
        self.ui2 = loader1.load(file1); 
        file1.close();          
        self.ui2.show();
        self.ui2.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.get);


  def show(self):
        self.ui.show();

  def clear1(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit.clear();

  def get(self):

        name1 = self.ui2.lineEdit.text();
        name2 = self.ui2.lineEdit_2.text();

        f = open('data','a' );
        f.write(name1);
        f.write('#');
        f.write(name2);
        f.write('\n');
        f.close();
        self.load();
        self.ui2.close();

  def load(self):
        f = open('data', 'r');
        for i in range(0, 10):
            string = f.readline();
            l=len(string);
            print(string);
            print(l);
            for  c in range(0, l-1):
                if string[c]=="#":
                   break;
                print(c);       
                name1=string[0:c];
                name2=string[c+1:l-1]; 
                self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(i, 0, QTableWidgetItem(name1));
                self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(i, 1, QTableWidgetItem(name2));
                i =i+1;

  def sort(self):
        f=open('data', 'r');
        f.readlines().sort();

  if __name__ == '__main__':

        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        app.setApplicationName('PhoneBook Application')

        w = PhoneBook();
        w.show();

        QObject.connect(app, SIGNAL('lastWindowClosed()'), app,SLOT('quit()'))

        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

setup.py

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable

includefiles = ['Add.ui', 'PhoneBook.ui', 'data', 'web.png']
includes = ["re"]
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
   base = "Win32GUI"
setup(name="PhoneBook", version="3.0",description="Test",options = {'build_exe':  {'include_files':includefiles, 'includes' : includes}
```

Is it because I am using QUILoader ? However on executing the Python code directly its showing correct results. Please help me.

Comment: Check where it's looking for `PhoneBook.ui` - you may need to give it the location of that file.

Comment: I tried it by making resource file but it went in vain. As I am usingPython 3.3 I cannot use py2exe or pyinstaller. Please help.

Comment: Try putting `Phonebook.ui` in the same folder as the executable, and getting the code to look for `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable), 'Phonebook.ui')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs its seems that you must include atexit

> cxfreeze yourapp.py --target-dir dist --base-name Win32GUI --include-modules atexit,PySide.QtNetwork --icon yourapptaskgroup.ico

The site specifically mentions that if you don't include atextit , the installer is not going to work

> “atexit” must be included in —include-modules, otherwise the generated exe will fail.

[Link to the knowledge base article](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Packaging_PySide_applications_on_Windows)

Comment: Thanks, I've opened an issue on cx_Freeze to include atexit automatically with PySide: https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/36/pyside-requires-atexit

Answer (score 0):

Another cause of error was that cx-freeze was using some dlls from PyQt.

And the dlls are not same in pyside and pyqt, so if you have pyqt insalled i would suggest adding **PyQt4** to the excludes

```
excludes=['PyQt4', 'tcl', 'tk', 'ttk', 'tkinter', 'Tkconstants', 'Tkinter', "collections.sys", "collections._weakref"]
```